# Filter ArrayList from Database

Tags: android, mysql, arrays, arraylist, filter

I want to filter an `ArrayList` from a Database. Here´s my code were I filter the Array:

```
if (miId == 2) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item_list_asistencia, viewGroup, false);

    return new MetaViewHolder(v, this);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

It's working well but the problem is that when `miId != 2`, it execute `null` and I get this error

> Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View >android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object >reference

Its another posibility of return?

Before creating the array:

```
public void cargarAdaptador() {

    // Petición GET

    Log.d("DIATX", String.valueOf(11));
    VolleySingleton.
            getInstance(getActivity()).
            addToRequestQueue(
                    new JsonObjectRequest(
                            Request.Method.GET,
                            Constantes.GET_Asistencia,
                            null,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    // Procesar la respuesta Json
                                    procesarRespuesta(response);
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.toString());
                                }
                            }

                    )
            );
}
 public void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        // Obtener atributo "estado"
        String estado = response.getString("estado");
switch (estado) {
    case "1": // EXITO
        // Obtener array "metas" Json
        JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");

        Meta_Asistencia[] metas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Meta_Asistencia[].class);

        // APLICACIÓN DE ORDEN:
        // Ordenar el array de metas por idMeta de forma descendente:
        Arrays.sort(metas, new Comparator<Meta_Asistencia>() {
            int result;
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

            @Override
            public int compare(Meta_Asistencia objeto1, Meta_Asistencia objeto2) {
                // Comparamos por fechaLim de forma descendente:
                try {
                    result = f.parse(objeto2.dia).compareTo(f.parse(objeto1.dia));
                    Log.d("DIA", objeto1.dia);
                    Log.d("DIA1", objeto2.dia);
                    Log.d("ordenar", String.valueOf(result));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;

            }
        });

        // Inicializar adaptador
        adapter = new MetaAdapter_Asistencia(Arrays.asList(metas), getActivity());
        // Setear adaptador a la lista
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressBar_first.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

My new filter code:

```
 // Inicializar adaptador
                Log.d("DIATX", String.valueOf(8));
                for(int i=0;i<metas.size();i++){
                    if(metas.getObject(i).miId != null){
                        filteredArr.put(metas.getObject(i));
                    }
                }
                adapter = new MetaAdapter_Asistencia(Arrays.asList(metas), 
                getActivity(), myId);
                // Setear adaptador a la lista
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

                progressBar_first.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Your question is little unclear, which array are you trying to filter? And if you are returning null instead of a view holder why would't it throw an exception.

Comment: I want to filter the adapter, but I think that I need to filter it before creating it because the error of the null. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

There should never be a null value returned in place of view. Make your if conditions on the adapter such that it handles every condition and returns a view for that condition. It should never return null in place of view otherwise the app will crash as **the adapter needs some kind of view to show its contents**.

```
if (miId == 2) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
    .inflate(R.layout.item_list_asistencia, viewGroup, false);

    return new MetaViewHolder(v, this);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

The else part should send a view. When it sends null the adapter will crash.

So what you  should do is that you should return a view for every if condition such that if miId is 2, you are returning view of item_list_asistencia and for other values it should return a **different view but not null**

1.Make a seperate Array named filteredArr;

2.Before sending to adapter, forloop the array `metas`. In the forloop, if `Meta_Asistencia objeto1.miId` is null, don't put the object into filteredArr else put into filteredArr

So loosely

```
for(int i=0;i<metas.size();i++){
    if(metas.getObject(i).miId != null){
        filteredArr.put(metas.getObject(i));
    }
}
```

*No object with miId == null is stored in the filtered array.*

3.Pass filteredArr into the adapter.

Comment: So should I put the if condition after "Meta_Asistencia[] metas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), MetaAsistencia[].class);"?

Comment: @Ismael i have updated the answer. Please check and confirm to me after you update your code

Comment: So because this, I cannot filter it in the array because it will send null answers that results in crash, I need to filter it before. Because I only want to show in the screen the values I am filtering for example I want to only show the values that have myId 2

Comment: Yes so if some ids have null values either you pass them to your adapter and return a view for those null ids or omit those null ids before you pass them to your adapter.

Comment: I don't know how to do, I tried filteringit inside public int compare(Meta_Asistencia objeto 1, Meta_Asistencia objeto 2) but without any results

Comment: Simple. Just make a JsonArray variable named filteredJsonValues which will contain all the filtered values which doesn't have the null ids and everytime you filter, you put the filtered json values in this variable. Pass this variable to the adapter.

Comment: Could you make me a coed example? I'm new using Json thanks in advance

Comment: ok Please check and then verify with me. Am updating the answer with code

Comment: Ok, update the answer, I will check and show if it works, thanks!

Comment: @Ismael please check

Comment: So, with this code i got this error in metas Variable 'metas' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: // Inicializar adaptador
        adapter = new MetaAdapter_Asistencia(Arrays.asList(metas), getActivity()); Write the forloop before this code. You are passing metas variable in this adapter without declaring metas as final. So write the forloop before this line

Comment: So I get this error Cannot resolve method 'getObject(int)' and size, I update my code

Comment: Hi, again, ive done the 3 steps but how to pass into the adapter, Thanks!